# Setting a post-authentication View for Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I have an MVC4 Intranet application (using the default template). I am using Windows Authentication as my login system, however, i want to be able to capture some details from the user the first time they register with the site.

**Use Cases**

1. First time user authenticates using their AD login (currently working). They are presented with an 'Enter your Details' View.
2. Second time user authenticates using their AD login. They are taken
   straight to the home screen.

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: Create a custom Authorize Attribute in which you check if there are Details for the user saved in the database, if not, redirect the user to the 'Enter your Details' View.

Comment: Can you post an answer to that effect, with some lightweight code examples? I was hoping there was a way to direct them to a View on Authorization (much like there is with Forms Auth). I also will need to know how to get their details from windows auth if i am to implement a custom attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom AuthorizeAttribute like this:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private UnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = false;
        var username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        // Some code to find the user in the database...
        var user = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Find(username);
        if(user != null)
        {
           // Check if there are Details for the user in the database
           if(user.HasDetails)
           {
             isAuthorized = true;
           }
        }


        return isAuthorized;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {            
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (!AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
           // If not authorized, redirect to the Details action 
           // of the Account controller... 

           var action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
           if(filterContext.Controller is AccountController 
             && action.Equals("Details"))
           {
             // Do nothing
           }
           else
           {
             filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
               new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary {
                 {"controller", "Account"}, {"action", "Details"}
               }
             );
           }               
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it in your Controllers like this:

```
[MyAuthorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

Or, you can register it as a global action filter in your Global.asax file like this:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new MyAuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Comment: As an aside, can you please add a check in to validate that the action being called is not the Details action? Otherwise we get a loop.